# How to show mapping cones are homotopy cofibers

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, dg-categories

In a dg-category $\mathcal{C}$, the *$n$-translation* of an object $C$ is an object $C[n]$ representing the functor
$$
{\rm Hom}(-,C)[n].
$$
The *cone* of a closed morphism $f\colon C \to D$ of degree zero is an object 
${\rm Cone}(f)$ representing the functor
$$
{\rm Cofiber}\big({\rm Hom}(-,C)
\stackrel{{f_{\ast}}}{\longrightarrow}{\rm Hom}(-,D)\big).
$$
On the other hand, the *homotopy cofiber* of $f$ is an object 
${\rm Cofiber}(f)$ representing the functor
$$
{\rm Fiber}\big({\rm Hom}(D,-)
\stackrel{{f^{\ast}}}{\longrightarrow}{\rm Hom}(C,-)\big).
$$

Now, suppose $\mathcal{C}$ has zero object, all translations of all objects, and all cones of all morphisms.

My question: **Is there any easy way to show ${\rm Cofiber}(f)$ and ${\rm Cone}(f)$ are isomorphic?**

To be more efficiently, I know that there are canonical 
closed morphism $\iota\colon D\to{\rm Cone}(f)$ of degree $0$ and 
morphism $h\colon C\to{\rm Cone}{f}$ of degree $-1$. They induce a natural cochain map
$$
{\rm Hom}\big({\rm Cone}(f),-\big)
\longrightarrow
{\rm Fiber}\big({\rm Hom}(D,-)
\stackrel{{f^{\ast}}}{\longrightarrow}{\rm Hom}(C,-)\big)
$$
which sends any $x\colon{\rm Cone}(f)\to X$ to 
the pair $(x\circ\iota,x\circ h)$.

However, I don't know how to finish the proof, i.e. show this is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

A very short answer would be as follows. What you define to be $\mathrm{Cone}(f)$ lies in a triangle in $\mathcal C$:
 \begin{equation}
 C \xrightarrow{f} D \to \mathrm{Cone}(f),
\end{equation}
whereas what you define as $\mathrm{Cofiber}(f)$ lies in a triangle in $\mathcal C^{\mathrm{op}}$:
 \begin{equation}
 \mathrm{Cofiber}(f)[-1] \to  D \xrightarrow{f^\mathrm{op}} C.
\end{equation}
This triangle in $\mathcal C^\mathrm{op}$ is the same as the previous triangle in $\mathcal C$.